# Writing a Novel

Tags: novel, editing, grammar

So, I am writing a story. I have book 1 done, half of book 2 and of course the ending in book 3. I am not an English major, and I am not at all great with grammar, or using proper English. Which programs are the best to put my rough draft through to make sure that it is "Proper English" ? Online free apps, or programs would be helpful.

Not just Grammar, but punctuation, sentence enhancing, story flow, ect.

Comment: "Sentence enhancing" and "story flow" must be done by a human, or several humans. You can do some basic polishing with software, but you'll need beta readers and an editor to bring the entire work together.

Answer (score 1):

For all of this there is nothing better than reading and rereading.  By the time you have fully proofed the story yourself you will know it inside and out, and there will still be errors you can't see.  After you've gone through and checked yourself a couple of times, have a friend read it and help you proof through it.